# Pandas, Using generated values while iterating through rows within grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to Pandas and programming in general but I've always been able to find the answer to any problem through google until now.  Sorry about the not terribly descriptive question, hopefully someone can come up with something clearer.

I'm trying to group data together, perform functions on that data, update a column and then use the data from that column on the next group of data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(9),columns=['A'])
df['B'] = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]
df['C'] = np.nan
df['D'] = np.nan
df.loc[0:2,'C'] = 500
```

Giving me

```
    A           B   C       D
0   0.825828    1   500.0   NaN
1   0.218618    1   500.0   NaN
2   0.902476    1   500.0   NaN
3   0.452525    2   NaN     NaN
4   0.513505    2   NaN     NaN
5   0.089975    3   NaN     NaN
6   0.282479    3   NaN     NaN
7   0.774286    3   NaN     NaN
8   0.408501    3   NaN     NaN
```

The 500 in column C is the initial condition.  I want to group the data by column B and perform the following function on the first group

```
def function1(row):
    return row['A']*row['C']/6
```

giving me

```
    A           B   C       D
0   0.825828    1   500.0   68.818971
1   0.218618    1   500.0   18.218145
2   0.902476    1   500.0   75.206313
3   0.452525    2   NaN     NaN
4   0.513505    2   NaN     NaN
5   0.089975    3   NaN     NaN
6   0.282479    3   NaN     NaN
7   0.774286    3   NaN     NaN
8   0.408501    3   NaN     NaN
```

I then want to sum the first three values in D and add them to the last value in C and making this value the group 2 value

```
    A           B   C           D
0   0.825828    1   500.000000  68.818971
1   0.218618    1   500.000000  18.218145
2   0.902476    1   500.000000  75.206313
3   0.452525    2   662.243429  NaN
4   0.513505    2   662.243429  NaN
5   0.089975    3   NaN         NaN
6   0.282479    3   NaN         NaN
7   0.774286    3   NaN         NaN
8   0.408501    3   NaN         NaN
```

I then perform function1 on group 2 and repeat until I end up with this

```
    A           B   C           D
0   0.825828    1   500.000000  68.818971
1   0.218618    1   500.000000  18.218145
2   0.902476    1   500.000000  75.206313
3   0.452525    2   662.243429  49.946896
4   0.513505    2   662.243429  56.677505
5   0.089975    3   768.867830  11.529874
6   0.282479    3   768.867830  36.198113
7   0.774286    3   768.867830  99.220591
8   0.408501    3   768.867830  52.347246
```

The dataframe will consist of hundreds of rows.  I've been trying various groupby, apply combinations but I'm completely stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
df['D'] = df['A'] * df['C']/6

for i in df['B'].unique()[1:]:
    df.loc[df['B']==i, 'C'] = df['D'].sum()
    df.loc[df['B']==i, 'D'] = df['A'] * df['C']/6
```

Comment: Try the short version :)

Comment: That seems to work. I just had to change the third line to 

df.loc[df['B']==i, 'C'] = df['D'].sum() + 500

Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.unique()` for the selction. In your code this might look somehow like this:

```
import numpy as np
import math

unique, indices, counts = np.unique(df['B'], return_index=True, return_counts=True)

for i in range(len(indices)):
    for j in range(len(counts)):
        row = df[indices[i]+j]
        if math.isnan(row['C']):
            row['C'] = df.loc[indices[i-1], 'D']  
        # then call your function
        function1(row)
```